# Meu código não envia email para o Gmail, porém envia para Hotmail

Tags: java, email, socket

Meu código por algum motivo não envia emails para o Gmail, bom, pelo menos não chegam os emails. Isso é um trabalho de faculdade, eu ganhei a pontuação, portanto sem pressa, porém isso está me encucando, qual o problema? Pois eu consigo enviar para o hotmail, mas para o Gmail tenho problemas. Meu protocolo está certo? Coloquei aqui só o código base, porém, eu estou usando uma interface gráfica (swing) para rodar o código.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
/**
 * 
 * @author Joubert Joe Vieira Lellis
 *
 */
public class ProtocoloEmail {

    public String log;


    /**
     * 
     * @param emailBody - Corpo do email - Body of the Email
     * @param emailSubject - Assunto do EMail - Subject of the Email
     * @param emailSender - Remetente do email - Email Sender
     * @param emailRecipient - Destinatï¿½rio do Email - Email Recipiente
     * @param emailHost - HOST (Gmail, Hotmail, Yahoo)
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws UnknownHostException
     */
    public void enviar( String emailBody, String emailSubject, String emailSender,String emailRecipient,String emailHost, String password) throws IOException, UnknownHostException{

        SMTP mail = new SMTP(emailHost);
        // Protocolo - Protocol (Simple Mail Transpor Protocol)

        if (mail != null) {
            if (mail.send(emailSubject , emailBody, emailSender, emailRecipient, password)) {
                log = ("Email Enviado \n Mail Sent");
            } else {
                log = ("Falha ao conectar com servidor SMTP \n Connect to SMTP server failed!");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Pronto. \n Done.");
    }

/**
 * 
 * @author Joubert Joe Vieira Lellis
 *
 */
    static class SMTP {
        private final static int SMTP_PORT = 587; // Porta padrï¿½o SMTP - Default Port SMTP
        InetAddress mailHost;
        InetAddress localhost;
        BufferedReader in;
        PrintWriter out;

        /**
         * 
         * @param   host Host a ser usado - Host to be used. Ex: (gmail, hotmail, yahoo, etc...)
         * @throws  UnknownHostException Tratamento de exceï¿½ï¿½o de Host - Host Exception
         */
        public SMTP(String host) throws UnknownHostException {
            mailHost = InetAddress.getByName(host);
            localhost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            System.out.println("mailhost = " + mailHost);
            System.out.println("localhost= " + localhost);
            System.out.println("Contrutor SMTP pronto. /n SMTP constructor done\n");
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param msgEmail      Mensagem contendo Assunto e corpo de email - Mensage includind subject and body of the email.
         * @param from          Quem vai enviar o email - Who gonna send that Email.
         * @param to            Quem estï¿½ recebendo o email - Who gonna recieve that email.
         * @return              Booleana para saber se tudo ocorreu bem - Boolean to check if everythings is right.
         * @throws IOException  Possï¿½veis erros - Possible errors.
         */
        public boolean send(String msgAssunto, String msgEmail, String from, String to, String pass) throws IOException {
        //  SSLSocket smtpSocket;
            Socket smtpSocket;
            InputStream inn;
            OutputStream outt;

        // Criptografia 
            String user = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(from.getBytes("utf-8"));
            pass = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(pass.getBytes("utf-8"));

        //  smtpSocket = (SSLSocket) ((SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault()).createSocket(mailHost, SMTP_PORT);
            smtpSocket = new Socket(mailHost, SMTP_PORT);

            if (smtpSocket == null) {
                return false;
            }
            inn = smtpSocket.getInputStream();
            outt = smtpSocket.getOutputStream();
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inn));
            out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outt), true);
            if (inn == null || outt == null) {
                System.out.println("Failed to open streams to socket.");
                return false;
            }
            String initialID = in.readLine();
            System.out.println(initialID);
            System.out.println("HELO ailton.eng.br");
            out.println("HELO ailton.eng.br");
            out.flush();
            String welcome = in.readLine();
            System.out.println(welcome);
            System.out.println("AUTH LOGIN");
            out.println("AUTH LOGIN");
            out.flush();
            out.println(user);
            out.flush();
            System.out.println(user);
            out.println(pass);
            out.flush();
            System.out.println(pass);

            System.out.println("MAIL From:<" + from + ">");
            out.println("MAIL FROM:<" + from + ">");
            out.flush();

            String senderOK = in.readLine();
            System.out.println(senderOK);

            System.out.println("RCPT TO:<" + to + ">");
            out.println("RCPT TO:<" + to + ">");
            out.flush();
            String recipientOK = in.readLine();
            System.out.println(recipientOK);

            System.out.println("DATA");
            out.println("DATA");
            out.flush();

            out.println("Subject: " +msgAssunto);
            out.flush();
            System.out.println(msgAssunto);

            out.println(msgEmail + "\n.\nQUIT\n");
            out.flush();
            System.out.println(msgEmail);

            System.out.println(".");

            out.flush();
            System.out.println("QUIT");
        //  out.println("QUIT");
            out.flush();
            String acceptedOK = in.readLine();
            String resposta;



            System.out.println(acceptedOK);
            /*
            do{
               resposta = in.readLine();

               System.out.println(resposta);
            }while(resposta != null); 
             */

            return true;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Eu sei arquivos JavaScript não podem ser enviados, e RAR/ZIP é muito dificil de ser enviado, pior ainda pra ser recebido. Acontece apenas com esse código ?

Comment: A questão é que não consigo enviar mensagens simples.
PS : Porém, eu consigo enviar as mensagens normalmente para o Hotmail.

Comment: utilize o smtp:  smtp-relay.gmail.com

Comment: Vou tentar, assim caso tenha resultados eu posto aqui com o código corrigido, vou dar uma olhada , caso eu ache alguma outra solução posto também.